# Using PHP how can I load 1000s of configuration files into a database?

Tags: php, performance, refactoring

In a folder I have 34,000 configuration files. Each file contains an object that has unique configuration specs. Here is an example of the contents of a file:

```
$obj = new obj();
$obj->name = "name":
$obj->location "nyc";
...
...
etc
```

Each file is about 100 to 200 lines long and is about 17k in size.

To get these into the database, I have the following function:

```
function retrieve_files(){
    $objs = array();

    $path = 'filefolder';

    //retrieve a list of files as an array of objects
    $files = get_files('/\.inc$/', $path, 'filename', 0);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
            include_once $path.'/'.$file->filename;
            $objs[$obj->name] = $obj;
    }

    return $objs;
}
```

Once the object array is returned, it's looped over in another function, serialized, and each is saved into the database.

Currently, my server is an Intel dual core 3.06 Ghz processor with 8 Gigs of RAM.  I am running the script via the command line in Ubuntu 12.04.

As the script processes CPU maxes out at 100% and memory climbs until all 8 gigs have maxed out. The script then crashes.

How can I make this script, or process overall, more efficient?  Preferably I would prefer to stay within the scope of this function.  I would also prefer to do this in one pass.  Is there a way to refactor this that uses less resources or frees up resources at the arrays are created and loops are iterated over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than returning all the objects, do it say 100 objects at a time. So something like this

```
function retrieve_files(){
    $objs = array();

    $path = 'filefolder';

    //retrieve a list of files as an array of objects
    $files = get_files('/\.inc$/', $path, 'filename', 0);
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
            include_once $path.'/'.$file->filename;
            $objs[$obj->name] = $obj;
            if ( $count++%100 == 0 )
            {
                function_to_process_obj($objs);
                $objs = null;
                $objs = array();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you have too much objects in your final array at the end of your first function.

34 000 files means 34 000 objects in your array `$objects`.

May be you should save the object in your loop. For each file included, you save in the database your serialized object. You will have 1 line in DB for 1 configuration file.